# Permission denied @ rb_sysopen gem install pg on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed `postgresql, libpq-dev and build-essential`. When I ran `gem install pg`, I got a

```
ERROR:  Error installing pg:

ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

I tried every solution I found in stackoverflow, but none of them worked. However, now I ran `gem install pg`, I got a new error

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/woyuxuxu123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/pg-0.21.0/.gemtest
```

Could anyone help me on this? I have been stuck on this for a whole afternoon.

Comment: Somebody helps please.

Comment: did you install using sudo? (If you did not use sudo when installing ruby, please disregard this comment!) if so you need to install gems using sudo. This solution is not recommended. You may need to reinstall ruby with out using sudo. here is a nice guide for installing ruby on rails with rbenv https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-16-04.

Answer (score 0):

Use sudo before installing the gem or update in your system as like this:

`sudo apt update
gem install pg`